# mysql convert rows to cols from one table dynamic

Tags: mysql

I have table has data as

```
id | qs | ans         
=============
1  | qs1|ans1 
1  | qs2|ans2
```

I need to get data from this table as

```
id | qs1 | qs2 
1  | ans1| ans2
```

note I don't know how much rows will be with the same id and I don't know the data in qs cell  so I cant use case my data is text, not a number

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns

Comment: `so I cant use case` that's very unfortunate because there is no alternative in MySQL (so far).

Comment: yes, you are right but what I mean the qs cols may have different data some time number some time text for that I mean that I cant use code with case like case(color then ) it should be case(? then )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)

Comment: @HakamKarawi Why do you want to read the data from the database this way? Why not read it in the "normal" way?

Comment: @Progman this data survey results and to analyze this data every survey should be in one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE qanda
>     (`id` int, `qs` varchar(100), `ans` varchar(100));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO qanda
>     (`id`, `qs`, `ans`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'qs1', 'ans1'),
>     (1, 'qs2', 'ans2'),
>     (1, 'qs3', 'ans3'),
>     (1, 'qs4', 'ans4'),
>     (1, 'qs5', 'ans4'),
>     (2, 'qs1', 'ans1'),
>     (2, 'qs2', 'ans2'),
>     (2, 'qs3', 'ans3'),
>     (2, 'qs4', 'ans4');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('max(IF(qs=\'',qs,'\', ans, NULL)) AS `',`qs`,'`')
> into @query
> FROM qanda
> where id = 1;
>
> SET @query := concat('select id,',@query,' from qanda where id = 1 group by id');
> PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @query;
> EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | qs1  | qs2  | qs3  | qs4  | qs5 
> -: | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :---
>  1 | ans1 | ans2 | ans3 | ans4 | ans4
> ```

*[dbfiddle demo here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=163ffc582333e0b27a5d942d793b90b1)*